# Setting Default Code Editor for New Project in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Friends -
I recently moved from Visual Studio 2019 to VS 2022.  Before change, any LTS version of Unity worked, opened up scripts seamlessly.
However, after upgrade, I have to update the preferences on -each- project, new or old, to use VS2022.
I know to go to EDIT>PREFERENCES>EXTERNAL TOOLS, and change External Script Editor combo box to "Microsoft Visual Studio 2022"...
but how do I change the default on ALL projects, not just the current?

**tldr; need to change default editor for all unity projects, not just current one.**

thanks!

Comment: If the project cannot be opened in the new editor. Solution: In the Packages folder under the project, remove "com.unity.collab-proxy" in the manifest and packages-lock, and restart the project. This may be caused by conflict with other packages after collab update.

Comment: @HouSheng-MSFT - I'm not sure I understand your answer.  you start by saying, "If the project cannot be opened in the new editor."  I never said any project couldn't open.  All projects open.  It is the default code editor I'm trying to change.